# How to create 2 captured groups and replace them in Intelij Idea/Android Studio?

Tags: regex, android-studio

I want to find this: `(?<name>lastBid = \d+?),(?<name2>lastBid = \d?)`
and replace with this `${name}\nrandomtext|${name2}\nrandomtexts`. How can I do it? I get no matches in text:

```
     lastBid = 25
        lastBid = 3
```

Edit:
Ok, if I want to use some text between two lastBid's. For example:

```
  lastBid = 25
dfdfdfdf
lastBid = 3
```

if I use:
`(?<name>lastBid = 2[0-5])|(?<name2>lastBid = [0-9])`
and in replacement:
`${name}\nrandomtext\n${name2}\nrandomtexts`
I get this:

```
 lastBid = 25
randomtext

randomtexts
dfdfdfdf
    
randomtext
lastBid = 3
randomtexts
```

but my expectation is this:

```
 lastBid = 25
randomtext
dfdfdfdf
lastBid = 3
randomtexts
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(?<name>lastBid = \d+?),(?<name2>lastBid = \d?)` matches:

`lastBid = 25,lastBid = 3`

To match

```
 lastBid = 25
    lastBid = 3
```

you need `(?<name>lastBid = \d+)\s+(?<name2>lastBid = \d)`

where `\s*` stands for 0 or more spaces (including linebreak).

---

**Edit according to resquest change:**

- Find: `(?<name>lastBid = 2[0-5])([\s\S]*?)(?<name2>lastBid = [0-9])`
- Replace: `${name}\nrandomtext$2${name2}\nrandomtexts`

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/5vbobO/1/)

Comment: Ok, if I want to use some text between two lastBid's. For example:
  lastBid = 25
dfdfdfdf
    lastBid = 3
if I use:
`(?<name>lastBid = 2[0-5])|(?<name2>lastBid = [0-9])`
and in replacement:
`${name}\nrandomtext\n${name2}\nrandomtexts`
I get this:
` lastBid = 25
randomtext

randomtexts
dfdfdfdf
    
randomtext
lastBid = 3
randomtexts`
but my expectation is this:
` lastBid = 25
randomtext
dfdfdfdf
lastBid = 3
randomtexts`
How can I do that?

Comment: Please see this [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gDC_-LWlTkze4GFQMAfDCAGhiGCAmaEY/view?usp=sharing). Stack Exchange doesn't show linebreaks as I want.

Comment: @GrandPC: Don't use alternation. use `(?<name>lastBid = 2[0-5])([\s\S]*?)(?<name2>lastBid = [0-9])` and replace `${name}\nrandomtext$2${name2}\nrandomtexts`. See https://regex101.com/r/5vbobO/1